# Obtener filas del registro con valor máximo

Tags: oracle

necesito obtener  el valor del campo RESULTADO del mayor SEGUIMIENTO, para cada caso en que (CODIGO y NUMERO) formen un único valor. Agradeceré puedan ayudarme.

[image: Tabla y Resultado deseado]

Comment: Bienvenido Erick Montes de Oca a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es una consulta en sql, quedaría algo así:

```
    SELECT CODIGO, NUMERO, SEGUIMIENTO, RESULTADO FROM TABLA T
WHERE SEGUIMIENTO = (SELECT MAX(SEGUIMIENTO) FROM TABLA U WHERE T.CODIGO = U.CODIGO);
```

Estimado, edité la respuesta por tu requerimiento para el resultado tal cual como lo necesitas en la tabla.

Espero te sirva

[Fiddle de prueba](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f75bc/2)

Comment: Gracias harifo, ejecuté la qwery, pero sólo arroja el máximo seguimiento de toda la tabla, cuando lo que requiero es que arroje el RESULTADO del máximo seguimiento, pero no de toda la tabla, sino de cada concatenación de CODIGO y NUMERO, tal como en el ejemplo 'RESULTADO:'. Agradezco tu apoyo

Comment: Edité la respuesta amigo, veela y me comentas

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:
con la clausula **max** y **rownum**

ejemplo:

```
select * from (select * from TABLA
order by SEGUIMIENTO desc) 
where rownum = 1;
```